Pivot the column size of 50,000 and input file size is 17 TBs
I have parquet files in aws s3 with size of 17 TBs with below schema and Unique Ids values are of size 50,000 :
UUID, Id
Which need to be transformed into below data structure(Basically Pivoting):
UUID, Id1, Id2, Id3,......
This output has to be written back into aws s3 in new path.
I tried with below approaches:
unique_ids = membership_df.select("Id").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
#print(f"Number of unique IDs: {len(unique_ids)}")

pivoted_df = membership_df.groupBy("uuid").pivot("Id", unique_ids).agg(lit(1))
transformed_df = pivoted_df.fillna(0)

After running 10 hrs in databricks, failed because less space left on device, unable to initialize the HikariCP, connection time out etc. in different execution.
Used: r6id16xlarge 50 workers.
Can someone help me to get efficient way to transform this data please?

so for each uuid you have 50k ids each on a different row. and you want to turn that into a table with 50k columns instead? how will you be using that? can you explain your reasoning for needing this as as is an unusual need!

How many files are there? How many rows in each file? Is the data organised sequentially (so all the data for one UUID is located in continuous rows), or can the data for each UUID be spread throughout many files on random rows?
